# T-SQL Min and Max

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, min

I am trying to get the min and max values from the results of the first part of my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.[Recording Date], 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        TRIM([Document Number]), 
        '0','n'),'1','n'),'2','n'),'3','n'),'4','n'),'5','n'),'6','n'),'7','n'),'8','n'),'9','n') AS pattern
FROM 
    [TPEConversionTeam].[dbo].[KY_Shelby_Recorder_History] a
WHERE 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        TRIM([Document Number]),
        '0','n'),'1','n'),'2','n'),'3','n'),'4','n'),'5','n'),'6','n'),'7','n'),'8','n'),'9','n') = 'nnnnnn-n'
```

Expected results should be `1993-01-06` and `2023-12-31`:

[image]

But I'm getting everything back so looks like my subquery is not doing anything.

My whole query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.[Recording Date], 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        TRIM([Document Number]),
        '0','n'),'1','n'),'2','n'),'3','n'),'4','n'),'5','n'),'6','n'),'7','n'),'8','n'),'9','n') as pattern
FROM 
    [TPEConversionTeam].[dbo].[KY_Shelby_Recorder_History] a
WHERE   
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        TRIM([Document Number]),
        '0','n'),'1','n'),'2','n'),'3','n'),'4','n'),'5','n'),'6','n'),'7','n'),'8','n'),'9','n') = 'nnnnnn-n'
      (SELECT MIN([Recording Date]) AS MIN_DATE
       FROM [TPEConversionTeam].[dbo].[KY_Shelby_Recorder_History]
       UNION
       SELECT MAX([Recording Date]) AS MAX_DATE
       FROM [TPEConversionTeam].[dbo].[KY_Shelby_Recorder_History])
```

Comment: I think you will have to explain in your own words what this query is supposed to do and how you think it works ... especially ... what all the replacements for? It doesn't look very clear at all. As far as your second query goes I don't even think that is legal SQL.

Comment: As a general rule for asking questions about SQL, provide some sample input data (records in the table or tables) so we can run and test your query with some sample data and check if the output is as expected or not.

Comment: The replace is for the different formats of the Document Number.  What I was trying to accomplish is to filter by one of the formats 'nnnnnn-n' and then find the min and max records for the said criteria.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results, as formatted text **not** images

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is a very basic grouping query. I've left out all the replacements as that's irrelevant to the way you write the query - using a very simple replace function instead. This is not really about subquery, just about grouping.

```
declare @KY_Shelby_Recorder_History table (
    Id int identity(1,1),
    [Recording Date] date,
    [Document Number] nvarchar(100),
    primary key (Id))

insert into @KY_Shelby_Recorder_History (
    [Recording Date], [Document Number])
    values
    ('1993-01-08', '111-1'),
    ('1993-01-09', '111-1'),
    ('2023-12-29', '111-1'),
    ('2023-12-30', '111-1'),
    ('1993-01-06', '111111-1'),
    ('1993-01-07', '111111-1'),
    ('2023-12-30', '111111-1'),
    ('2023-12-31', '111111-1')

select
    min(a.[Recording Date]) as MinOfRecordingDate,
    max(a.[Recording Date]) as MaxOfRecordingDate, 
    replace(a.[Document Number], '1', 'n') as [pattern]
from
    @KY_Shelby_Recorder_History a
group by
    replace(a.[Document Number], '1', 'n')
```

result is:

| MinOfRecordingDate | MaxOfRecordingDate | Document Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1993-01-08 | 2023-12-30 | nnn-n |
| 1993-01-06 | 2023-12-31 | nnnnnn-n |

This is very fundamental sql covered in any introduction to sql so probably you need to focus on learning sql basics on your own for a bit so you know the basics.

Comment: Thank you, this is not the results I was expecting. I have written the same query but the replace function is added there to add the format of the document number and filter by that.

  select a.*
FROM [TPEConversionTeam].[dbo].[KY_Shelby_Recorder_History] a
where a.[Recording Date] in (
SELECT MIN ([Recording Date]) AS MIN_DATE
  FROM [TPEConversionTeam].[dbo].[KY_Shelby_Recorder_History]
union
select MAX ([Recording Date]) AS MAX_DATE
FROM [TPEConversionTeam].[dbo].[KY_Shelby_Recorder_History])

Comment: What I was trying to accomplish is to filter by one of the formats 'nnnnnn-n' from the documents field and then find the min and max records for the said criteria.

Comment: I have added sample data to show that the output is correct. If this does not work for you, you must clarify your question with sample data from the tables. To show that grouping can take into account more than one group, I've added sample data that would result in two groups (one for cases where the documents are numbered with a format like `nnnnnn-n` and the others like `nnn-n` - which is not exactly your criteria but good enough to show how it works.

Comment: Close! I think I can work around your suggestion.  Thank you so much for your patience.